# How to get the id of elements inside ng-include

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm triying to follow the [John Papa Style Guide](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/a1/README.md) and in one template I have 2 ng-includes, one for a sidenav and another one to the content. In the controller I want to get the id of one item inside the ng-include. How can I achieve that?

**EDIT 1**

Main Template:

```
</md-toolbar>
    <md-content class="content" ms-scroll>
        <div ng-include="'app/main/apps/scrumboard/views/dietas/content/lista.html'"></div>
     </md-content>
</md-sidenav>
```

the lista.html:

```
<div id="listContainer" dragular="vm.dragularOptions">
                    <md-card ng-repeat="food in portion.items" >
                        <md-card-content layout="row" layout-align="center center" >
                            <img class="md-avatar" alt="{{todos[0].who}}" />
                            <p>{{food.name}}</p>                                                            
                        </md-card-content>
                    </md-card>
                </div>
```

I have tried:

```
document.querySelector('#listContainer')
```

but it returns nulls

and if i wrap it in:

```
angular.element(document.querySelector('#listContainer'))
```

and save it in a variable i get an empty array, but if i console.log that, it return the object

Comment: Please post your code and templates, as well as what have you tried and what failed, so people can help you.

Comment: @НЛО Editet to include templates and some code I've tried

Comment: @Allan Alvarez Ortiz I am also facing similar issue in accessing id inside ng-include. By any chance you were able to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
var listContainer = angular.element(document.querySelectorAll('#listContainer'));
```

Comment: it still return an empty array :/